# How to fix CORS error when Node API calls through Apache server

Tags: php, node.js, apache, .htaccess

I added a virtual host `abc.local` for `127.0.0.1`

1. Angular app is running on `localhost:4000`
2. PHP API on `localhost:80`
3. Node 1 API on `localhost:4060`
4. Node 2 API on `localhost:3001`

PHP files are inside the **/admin/webp** folder,
Node files are inside the **/admin/webp/v2** and **/admin/webp/v1** folder respectively.

Below is the **.htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding, X-Auth-Token, content-type"
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.local$
    RewriteRule ^admin/webp/v2/(.*)$ http://localhost:4060/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^admin/webp/v1/(.*)$ http://localhost:3001/v1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

All rewrite rules are just working fine.
For example all calls to `abc.local/webp/v2/users` are redirected to `localhost:4060/users`.

However browser throws CORS error because of the rule

`RewriteRule ^admin/webp/v2/(.*)$ http://localhost:4060/$1 [L,R=301]`

Apache Server responds OPTIONS request to the node application with a 301 redirect (browser is expecting a 200).
Is there any workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone facing the same trouble, just replace `[L,R=301]` with `[L,P]`
(Requests are treated as proxy rather than redirect).
It will fix the problem.

```
RewriteRule ^admin/webp/v2/(.*)$  http://localhost:4060/$1 [L,P]

RewriteRule ^admin/webp/v1/(.*)$  http://localhost:3001/v1/$1 [L,P]
```

Answer (score 0):

(Your question lacks some details, therefore forgive me if I made wrong assumptions.)

If your app wants to make a cross-origin request to `http://abc.local/admin/webp/v2/users`, a request header like `Content-Type: application/json` will cause the browser to first make a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

```
OPTIONS http://abc.local/admin/webp/v2/users
Origin: http://localhost:4000
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type
... more Access-Control-Request-* headers ...
```

Because of

```
RewriteRule ^admin/webp/v2/(.*)$ http://localhost:4060/$1 [L,R=301]
```

the Apache Server responds to this OPTIONS request with a redirection

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://localhost:4060/admin/webp/v2/users
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
... other Access-Control-Allow-* headers ...
```

To prevent this, you could extend the `RewriteCond` so that it excludes OPTIONS requests from rewriting and respond to them with 200 OK.

Comment: If you exclude OPTIONS http://abc.local/admin/webp/v2/users requests then browser will throw 404

Comment: I liked your detailed explanation. I will update my question accordingly. Eventhough I got the right answer.